# Looking for help refining the while loops in a Java program designed to count the odd numbers being read in from user input

Tags: java

Good Morning All -

I am trying to refine a finished block of code that has an issue. The program reads an integer and outputs the number of odd numbers present in said integer. I am using a 'while' loop to offer the option to the user to either repeat this activity, or to end the program by way of inputting a negative integer. The loop is somewhat successful, though I am seeing unwanted repetition as well as eventually inaccurate data when the user tries multiple times. Any insight or advice regarding methods to refine my approach would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

class Digits{//start class

   public static void main(String[]args){//start main

      Scanner userin  = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Hello and welcome to my Digit Reader program!");
      System.out.println("In this program I will ask you for an integer, then I will tell you how many odd numbers were in the value you gave.");
      System.out.println("To refresh your memory, an integer is a whole number that is neither a fraction nor a decimal.");
      System.out.println("You will be able to do this over and over until you enter a negative integer.");
      System.out.print("Let's get started! Input an integer with a few digits (I.E. 23594) here: ");

      int oddcount = 0;
      int number = userin.nextInt();

      System.out.println("You entered " + number + " as your number to be read.");

      while (number > 0){//check to see if number is odd

         int remainder = number % 10;

         if (remainder % 2 !=0)

            oddcount++;

         number = number/10;
      }

      System.out.println("Your integer had " + oddcount + " odd numbers in it.");              
      System.out.println("Enter another positive integer, or enter a negative integer to quit: ");

      number = userin.nextInt();
      oddcount = 0;      

      System.out.println("You entered " + number + " as your number to be read.");

      while(number > 0){//making sure a user must enter a negative value to end the program

         int remainder = number % 10;

         if (remainder % 2 !=0)

            oddcount++;

         number = number/10;

         System.out.println("Your integer had " + oddcount + " odd integers in it."); 
      }

      System.out.println("Thank you for using my digit reader program!");
   }//end main
}//end class
```

Comment: you have code duplication, learn how to write methods to eliminate that. And your second last log statement is inside the while loop instead of outside.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, you're utilizing two loops which do the same thing.  There is one small exception to this stemming from the fact that you output the number of odd numbers *inside* your while loop in your *second* loop (which is why it works for the first number and tends to repeat for the second).

Aside from this and the text being outputted, the behavior is exactly the same.  So lets represent this in a nice method so it is easier to read:

And poof, like that we get to a more manageable:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Digits {// start class

    public static void main(String[] args) {// start main

        Scanner userin = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Hello and welcome to my Digit Reader program!");
        System.out.println("In this program I will ask you for an integer, then I will tell you how many odd numbers were in the value you gave.");
        System.out.println("To refresh your memory, an integer is a whole number that is neither a fraction nor a decimal.");
        System.out.println("You will be able to do this over and over until you enter a negative integer.");
        System.out.print("Let's get started! Input an integer with a few digits (I.E. 23594) here: ");

        int number = userin.nextInt();
        int oddcount = getOddNumberCount(number);

        System.out.println("Your integer had " + oddcount + " odd numbers in it.");
        System.out.println("Enter another positive integer, or enter a negative integer to quit: ");

        number = userin.nextInt();
        oddcount = getOddNumberCount(userin);

        System.out.println("Your integer had " + oddcount + " odd numbers in it.");
        System.out.println("Thank you for using my digit reader program!");
    }// end main

    private static int getOddNumberCount(int number) {
        int oddcount = 0;

        System.out.println("You entered " + number + " as your number to be read.");

        while (number > 0) {// check to see if number is odd
            int remainder = number % 10;
            if (remainder % 2 != 0)
                oddcount++;

            number = number / 10;
        }
        return oddcount;
    }
}// end class
```

Now we have a method getOddNumberCount which reads and calculates the number of odd numbers.  But this doesn't address the issue!  It doesn't repeat!

Written like this the reason is more apparent.  You're looping only *twice*.

So I would make the additional correction to the code so that the user can loop as many times as he or she wishes until a negative number is inputted:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Digits {// start class

    public static void main(String[] args) {// start main

        Scanner userin = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Hello and welcome to my Digit Reader program!");
        System.out.println("In this program I will ask you for an integer, then I will tell you how many odd numbers were in the value you gave.");
        System.out.println("To refresh your memory, an integer is a whole number that is neither a fraction nor a decimal.");
        System.out.println("You will be able to do this over and over until you enter a negative integer.");
        System.out.print("Let's get started! Input an integer with a few digits (I.E. 23594) here: ");

        int number = userin.nextInt();
        while(number >= 0) {
            int oddcount = getOddNumberCount(number);

            System.out.println("Your integer had " + oddcount + " odd numbers in it.");
            System.out.println("Enter another positive integer, or enter a negative integer to quit: ");

            number = userin.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Thank you for using my digit reader program!");
    }// end main

    private static int getOddNumberCount(int number) {
        int oddcount = 0;

        System.out.println("You entered " + number + " as your number to be read.");

        while (number > 0) {// check to see if number is odd
            int remainder = number % 10;
            if (remainder % 2 != 0)
                oddcount++;

            number = number / 10;
        }
        return oddcount;
    }
}// end class
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need an exit point. Let's assume exit point is negative numbers. Then you can use the following structure:

```
        while((num = scanner.nextInt()) > 0) {
           //Inner logic
        }

        {
            System.out.println("negative number!!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
```